# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-async-http

I am using `four` **Strings** in my code. The `first` String contains "`http://`", the `second` String contains user host URL (entered by user), the `third` contains "`/musics/a.mp3`" and the `fourth` String contains complete URL, by combining the previous Strings, like this:

```
String fourth = first+second+third;
```

Then I'm using the `fourth` String in `AsyncTask`'s execute, like this:

```
new JSONAsyncTask().execute(fourth);
```

And I'm getting the error below.

**Log:**

```
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at com.app.ifko.HomeActivity$JSONAsyncTask.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:101)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at com.app.ifko.HomeActivity$JSONAsyncTask.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-07 06:17:15.934: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     ... 5 more
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194): Activity com.app.ifko.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@416b80b0 that was originally added here
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.app.ifko.HomeActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@416b80b0 that was originally added here
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at com.app.ifko.HomeActivity$JSONAsyncTask.onPreExecute(HomeActivity.java:90)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at com.app.ifko.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:74)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-07 06:17:22.764: E/WindowManager(1194):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 06:17:24.144: I/Process(1194): Sending signal. PID: 1194 SIG: 9
```

**Activity code:**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

String first, second, third, fourth;
TextView etTextToSave;
private SharedPreferences  sharedprefs; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    etTextToSave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etTextToSave);      

    sharedprefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    etTextToSave.setText(sharedprefs.getString("SharedPrefsData",""));

    second = etTextToSave.getText().toString();     

    first = "http://";
    third = "/musics/a.mp3";            
    fourth = first+second+third;

    .........................

    new JSONAsyncTask().execute(fourth);

}
```

Comment: yes its null, but how may i control on this exception ?

Comment: put a `Log` or `SOP` before `new JSONAsyncTask().execute(fourth);`  and check what is your `fourth` string.

Comment: Log the urls in the asynctask? I guess your 'second' only contains "" from the sharedPrefs.

Comment: Try using `fourth = first.concat(second).concat(third);`

Comment: @DavidOlsson yes 'second' is null, but how may i control on this exception ?

Comment: @Sophie Do not execute the task if second is empty or null. Either have a check before you call the AsyncTask or within the AsyncTask itself. It's better to have it before you call the Task. I guess you need to take a look at your sharedPrefs to see why it's empty and nothing is saved (somewhere else in your code).

Comment: What does this give in console? Check once: `System.out.println("second: "+sharedprefs.getString("SharedPrefsData",""));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the host part of the URL comes from the user, you must validate it before using it to construct a URL.

Don't call `new JSONAsyncTask().execute(fourth);` if `second` is null.

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling `etTextToSave.getText()` in `onCreate()`, the returned text will be whatever there's by default in the layout and not what was entered by the user.

The code doesn't show if you're using an onclick listener or similar but if you are, move the `getText()` to the click handler.